# How can i connect Google Play In-App Reviews API with flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want the clear explanation regards how to integrate Google Play In-App Reviews API with flutter

I read the info regards integrate Google Play In-App Reviews API in Play Console. There instructions not available for connect with flutter

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [in_app_review](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review) plugin.  Then you can open the app store's review page using:

```
InAppReview.instance.openStoreListing(appStoreId: '<YOUR_APP_ID_NUMBER>');
```